# How to use the React Native Transitioner?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to change the default screen transition for Android from Bottom-To-Top to Right-To-Left. So this is what I'm doing:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import CardStackStyleInterpolator from 'react-navigation/src/views/CardStack/CardStackStyleInterpolator'

import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen3';

const StackComps = StackNavigator({
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1,
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2,
  },
  Screen3: {
    screen: Screen3,
  }
}, 

  {
    transitionConfig: ()=> {
      return {screenInterpolator: CardStackStyleInterpolator.default.forHorizontal}
    }
});


export default StackComps;
```

I'm getting the error:

[image]

I want all the screens transitions to be from Right-To-Left for Androis and iOS. For iOS i think it's already that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to their code, they are doing `default export` of an object as `export default {}`, therefore if you put one more default keyword, it will show the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

I changed the transitionConfig like this:

```
{
  transitionConfig: ()=> {
    return {screenInterpolator: CardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal}
  }
}
```

And this is working on Android. Hope this will work on iOS as well!